# Decoding algorithms for qLDPC codes

Tags: programming, error-correction, resource-request

Is there any open source decoding algorithm implementation for qLDPC codes under circuit-based noise model?

From the paper [arXiv:2308.07915](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.07915), I know that it is possible to adapt BP-OSD to circuit-based noise model, but I am struggling to follow the reasoning in that paper and finding any similar open source implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of the LDPC package that is currently under development, in the LDPC_V2 branch on LDPC's github repo, contains a Sinter BPOSD decoder.

This file contains an example of how to use it:
https://github.com/quantumgizmos/ldpc/blob/ldpc_v2/examples/sinter_example.py

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Peter-Jan. This is exactly what I am looking for. Could you please detail a bit about what are the current work that you guys are doing on the decoder? Can I expect to have comparable performance to the MWPM right now or there is still room for relative big improvements?

Comment: Yes, the performance in terms of runtime and decoding accuracy is similar to MWPM. Often you can squeeze out some more performance using a good choice of BPOSD settings. Right now I'm working on documentation to explain the different settings.